# GET url in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project. To get the uri segments I know I can use

```
$this->uri->segment();
```

but my case is a bit different

My url looks like

```
localhost/mediabox/home/box/21
```

but once I go to this url a popup form apears in which the user provide a key to access this page and I validate the key using ajax method which is inside my home controller validate_key function

when I echo the url it gives me localhost/home/validate_key

while calling valiate_key of the home controller how can I get the 21 from the url wrritten in the url bar?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem:

It's not a bug, it's a natural behavior.

**Consider the following:**

1. you request the `validate_key` function from the server by typing the URL in your address bar. `current_url()`  returns `localhost/blabla/validate_key`. *No AJAX involved.*
2. requesting `validate_key` with AJAX. The same PHP code will be executed.
   the `current_url()` will change to `localhost/blabla/validate_key`
   **even though your browser's address bar is showing `localhost/blabla/box/21`.**

So, what does this means? It means the Codeigniter `base_url()` doesn't care about your address bar, it cares about the function it is in, whether it was called via `ajax` or normal request.
 so as long this function is being executed, *the URL is pointing to it*.

### The solution:

My favorite solution to such a case, is to simply create a hidden input.

Simply, when a user requests the `box` function. you're showing him a popup form. so add a `hidden_input` field, give it a name and a value of 21(depends).

**For example(you should tailor this to your specific needs):**

Add this to your form in the view that get displayed by the `box` function:

`form_hidden("number", $this->uri->segment(3));`;

Now these data will be sent to your `validate_key` function. How do we access it? It's simple!

```
function validate_key(){

$this->input->post("number");//returns 21 or whatever in the URL.
//OR if the form sends GET request
$this->input->get("number");//return 21 or whatever in the URL.
/*
 *Or , you can do the following it's considered much safer when you're ONLY
 *expecting numbers, since this function(intval) will get the integer value of
 *the uri segment which might be a destructive string, so if it's a string
 *this function will simply return 0.
 */
$number = intval($this->input->post("number"));//returns 21 or whatever in the URL.
//Or if it it GET request:
$number = intval($this->input->get("number"));//returns 21 or whatever in the URL.
}
```

Comment: For this to work, make sure you have the form helper loaded `$this->load->helper('form');`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've used .htaccess to remove the `index.php` part of the url.  So, when you navigate to `localhost/mediabox/home/box/21` you're passing the value 21 to the function named `box` in the controller named `home`

If you want to keep that value within the `validate_key` function, just pass it through when calling it:

```
function box($param)
{
    //$param = 21
    $this->validate_key($param);
}
```

Comment: I am calling validate_key function using ajax not from inside the box function

Comment: Ok, so when you visit `localhost/mediabox/home/box/21` I'm guessing you load a view which then calls the `validate_key` function via ajax?  If that is true, my advice still applies: pass the `$param` down to the view, then pass it to the `validate_key` function as part of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Its better and suggetsed to use hidden field and post the value when it is needed.